# Dawnstar Sanctuary Secret Entrance Marker

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Is there a way to get the Dawnstar Sanctuary secret entrance on my world map? When I purchased this upgrade Delvin said I could get in and out of it. Coming out is fine, its a sewer grate outside of Dawnstar.

Getting in is the tricky part, since it is not marked on my world map. Short of stumbling looking for it once you get to Dawnstar, is there a mod that can mark this on my map? So I can fast travel from anywhere in the open world.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2.5 options:

- Put a user marker there (the blue marker placed by clicking on the map, won't allow fast travel but will make it easier to find) and never move it;
- If you're playing on PC, install a mod that adds a map marker there (as far as I know none exist due to the regular entrance having its own map marker, but you could make your own).
- Use the [Multiple Custom Markers with Notes](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/38731/?) mod to add a user map marker there that can be named and fast traveled to.

Comment: do you have a link to a mod?  he's asking for a mod in his question.  Also, I don't know if you can fast travel to user markers.

Comment: @z- nobody seems to have bothered making one because the regular entrance has its own marker.

Comment: What about looking in the local map?